# How to make a actionbar drop-down-menu that shows items horizontally?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar

I want to make a action-bar drop-down-menu that shows items (icons) horizontally. Like this:

[image]

This is suppose to be a action-bar withe drop-down menu, where you can choose a color.

So it should show the icons (colors) horizontally and the icons should be clickable. Until now I have only managed to make a vertical list.

If possible I would like to do this in XML.

Comment: Hmmmmm perhaps it could be done, though I don't think it's standard, particularly for an actionbar. See http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/ for an example w/o an actionbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ActionBar is not designed for such a use-case. The ActionBar buttons are meant to replace the old options menu that could be triggered with a separate hardware button on older devices (pre HC/ICS). The overflow button (the one with the 3 dots) that you've drawn in your sketch is used when there isn't enough room to show all buttons (the Android framework takes care of this automatically), so those will be grouped in the overflow menu. Overriding this behavior is a bad idea (if even possible).

Instead you should consider another approach: Add one ActionButton to the ActionBar that is meant to handle the color chooser. When this button is clicked the best solution is to show an AlertDialog (you can easily insert your on Views here that show the colors you want) because this will work best even if the button is hidden in the overflow menu.

Alternatively you could trigger a [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) or implement some QuickAction to handle the color chooser (this will probably suck if your button is hidden in the overflow menu and will also lead to a very confusing UI).